# @Loadbalanced - will it work with AsyncRestTemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I tried to follow "https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/124" (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/brewery/blob/master/brewing/src/main/java/io/spring/cloud/samples/brewery/bottling/BottlingConfiguration.java#L30) but it didn't help.
The loadBalancerInterceptor is not added to the AsyncRestTemplate.
When I debugged, I found that the interceptors are added/registered "after" all the beans are created - so AsyncRestTemplate gets created immediately after RestTemplate and before @Loadbalanced interceptor gets added.

Comment: Can you post your sample somewhere?

Comment: One additional info is: I have 2 "@Loadbalanced" RestTemplates and I want to pass only one of them to AsyncRestTemplate (for this I tried to use "@Qualifier" and also tried to specify the name corresponding to one of them - failed in both approaches - the interceptor was not added). I will now try to give you a sample project.

Comment: Have you tried to autowire a list of interceptors and add them manually? A sample would be really helpful

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak - here is a link to the Eureka client project - https://github.com/jot-hub/eureka-async-rest. The Eureka server needs to be setup and the eureka url should be updated in Eureka client project.

Comment: You're not wrapping your AsyncRestTemplate in a trace representation. Check this section of the docs - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.1.x/#_multiple_asynchronous_rest_templates (I added it yesterday).

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak - need a little bit more detail: My understanding of your suggestions is as follows: TraceAsyncRestTemplate solves 2 problems in 1 go - (1) make sure tracing is enabled for requests with AsyncRestTemplate by delegating calls via RestTemplate? (2) As a side-effect, the interceptors set for RestTemplate (including the LoadBalancerInterceptor) also comes into play and solves the original issue raised in the question - is this correct?

Comment: TraceAsyncRestTemplate registers a traced callback that takes care of passing tracing information. Also, the result of request execution is a traced representation of a ListenableFuture. And what you mentioned looks correct :)

Comment: Also, what exactly should go in CustomClientHttpRequestFactory? Looks like am missing something obvious here - is it not enough to use simpleclienthttprequestfactory?

Comment: You can build whatever ClientHttpRequestFactory you want. It can be the one that you've mentioned.

Comment: I don't have permission to upvote this yet - probably @MarcinGrzejszczak's comments could be moved to answers section.

Comment: Moved a comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrapping your AsyncRestTemplate in a trace representation. Check this section of the docs - cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/1.1.x/#_multiple_asynchronous_rest_templates (I added it yesterday).

UPDATE:

This PR https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/pull/149 fixes the problem with `AsyncRestTemplate` entirely in the Dalston release.

Comment: TraceAsyncRestTemplate still did not make sure LoadBalancerInterceptor is called - i.e. I continue to get "UnknownHostException" from Eureka - I updated the project - https://github.com/jot-hub/eureka-async-rest

Comment: am also looking at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/pull/149 - is that a more straight forward way to achieve the same?

Comment: The latest Dalston release of Spring cloud fixes this by adding @LoadBalanced support also to AsyncRestTemplate - project is updated with such changes (important changes are in the pom)- github.com/jot-hub/eureka-async-rest

Comment: It works with Dalston release - independent of TraceAsyncRestTemplate